# wordpress on apache2 not display correctly css only on windows host

Tags: css, wordpress, ubuntu, webserver, apache2

I did a recently installation of wordpress with apache2 on ubuntu server . The web can be displayed correctly on any host just display the html

I am new in the web world, so I don't have much skills in it

I was looking for and I suspect is a css problem compatibility
In windows host I have the following
[windows browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7raN.png)

I tried with all the possible wk , clear my cookies,other browser . etc
without results

Both machines live in the same network with the web server

Hope you can give some ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

When I was inspecting the page with google. I saw some objects like wp-config.php is not working, It have a message of resources can not be loaded, connection refused so I change the address url and site url on the wordpress configuration to my domain, and I enter on the web server(ubuntu) a entry for my domain in /etc/hosts with the local ip of my webserver